# Send Arguments from Batch File to Jython/Python

Tags: python, batch-file, jython, sikuli

I wrote a Sikuli script (Jython) to test a webpage.  The script contains multiple tests in it, which means that when one kills sikuli, the ones after it will not run.  To fix this, I'd like to instead call each test via a batch file.  So it is currently set up similar to this:

```
tests = [test1, test2, test3, test4]

for test in tests:
  run test
```

Obviously, that is a simplified version... so what I'd like to do is convert the list into 4 batch files.  The first batch file would call the script with test1 as an argument; the second would send test2 as an argument, etc.  I could then create another batch file to iterate through them.  However, I don't know how to communicate between a batch file and jython, other than just plainly running the script.

This question refers to both the batch file and jython scripts - I'm assuming you have to do something special in each.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is not 100% clear for me. I assume this is the answer:

First of all, you need to pass some arguments to Sikuli script started from batch file using **--args** option, for example:

```
YourPath\runIDE.cmd -r YourPath\YourScript.sikuli --args test1 test2 someOtherOption
```

Second of all, you must receive it in a script using **sys.argv** variable. It would work the same in either Python or Jython. Code sample:

```
import sys
print sys.argv

for a in sys.argv:
    if a=="test1":
        print "Do something"
    elif a=="test2":
        print "Do something else"
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv

Comment: that is what I'm looking for, thanks.  If I'm going to have a separate batch file for each, should I only include one test as an argument, though?  Different for each. So:
myPath\runIDE.cmd -r MyPath\MyScript.sikuli --args test1